# Run a method if Date is the next day

Tags: java, android, java.util.date

I want do something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

 int i = (int) (new Date().getTime()/1000);

   if(      ) // next day
     {
         mymethod();
     }
}
```

When in system date is a new day, then I want to call `mymethod()`

Comment: A new day in comparison to what? You would need a reference to another Date to compare if it is a day apart.

Comment: it is probably difficult

Comment: Not at all. Store the value in SharedPreferences. Then retrieve it when you need to and have a condition to determine if it is a day later.

Comment: What to do if I want to call only once a day this method?

Comment: Please note that you only write the code in Android Studio. Your question had nothing to do with Android Studio itself, and so that is why I edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With new day do you mean after midnight? So you want to detect if the date is different from last time?

```
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
     SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     int lastTimeStarted = settings.getInt("last_time_started", -1);
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     int today = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    if (today != lastTimeStarted) {
      //startSomethingOnce();

      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putInt("last_time_started", today);
      editor.commit();
    }
  }
```

Comment: for example
 
If time is 00:01 // It starts a new day {my mythod do something when I turn activity}

Comment: But I also want to induce mymethod() only once in a day

Comment: Then, you only need Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, today is the 73 day of 2016 and stays the same until midnight, after midnight it will be 74 day, that's when your app will start mymethod(). That method is called at most once a day.

Comment: Can you rewrite your code above, so I could see exactly what to do? It's really great idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use `Calendar` class instead of `Date`. You can check whether a day passed like this:

1. On some event, e.g. button click, app first start, save the time in sharedPreferences
2. Retrieve that value and compare it to the current time
   Just an illustration on how to do this:

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity);

       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
       int currentTimeSeconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

       SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       int secondsPreviousDay = prefs.getInt("seconds", 0);
       if (secondsPreviousDay != 0){ //means there was an earlier set value from previously entering the activity
           //compare if more than 3600*24 = 86400 (1 day in seconds) had passed
           if (currentTimeSeconds - secondsPreviousDay > 86400){
                mymethod();
           }
       }
       else {
           prefs.edit().putInt("seconds", currentTimeSeconds).apply();
       }
   }
   ```

In my code I've presumed that you want to see if a day has passed from the first time you've started this activity until the second time. You can tweak this to your preference, but I hope the idea is understandable.

> I know I could've compacted those 2 if's into one, but I just wanted it to be more clear what I was after.

Comment: Well then just put adding to the sharedPreferences wherever you like like and retrieve it someplace else and compare the value to the current time like in my code.. do you have any other questions?

Comment: My method will cause only one time in a day, not again and again right?

Comment: For that: just add one more little thing, either write new time into SharedPreferences every time you trigger your method OR keep some kind of day counter and an indicator as to whether the event already fired that day or not.

Answer (score 0):

Great idea!

In my first activity I set something like this inside onCreate :

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentTimeSeconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    SharedPreferences share = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edittime = share.edit();
    edittime.putInt("timevalue",currentTimeSeconds);
    edittime.commit();
```

and use your code in another activity inside onCreate:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int secondsPreviousDay = prefs.getInt("seconds", 0);
    if (secondsPreviousDay != 0){ //means there was an earlier set value from previously entering the activity
        //compare if more than 3600*24 = 86400 (1 day in seconds) had passed
        if (currentTimeSeconds - secondsPreviousDay > 86400){
           // mymethod();
            mymethod();

        }
    }
    else {
        prefs.edit().putInt("seconds", currentTimeSeconds).apply();
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for that but I'm still learning

Comment: you are using two different SharedPreferences, look:

Comment: SharedPreferences share = getSharedPreferences("TIME",MODE_PRIVATE);

AND 

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

You need it to be the same SharedPreferences.

Comment: Is Calendar.SECOND not only the seconds of the current minute? It doesn't make sense to compare that value with 86400.